# Need help with ansible

Tags: command-line, networking, server, bash, ansible

I have ansible project that automatically installs Patroni HA cluster.
Problem is in patroni.conf file.

It needs different configuration for every host.

For example:

Host 1 configuration:

```
scope: postgres
name: postgresql0

restapi:
    listen: 10.0.13.242:8008
    connect_address: 10.0.13.242:8008

etcd:
    host: 10.0.13.247:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.242/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.243/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.244/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.245/24 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: 10.0.13.242:5432 
    connect_address: 10.0.13.242:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: replicator_pass
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: postgres
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

Host 2 conf:

```
scope: postgres
name: postgresql0

restapi:
    listen: 10.0.13.243:8008
    connect_address: 10.0.13.243:8008

etcd:
    host: 10.0.13.247:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.242/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.243/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.244/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.245/24 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: 10.0.13.243:5432 
    connect_address: 10.0.13.243:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: replicator_pass
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: postgres
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

Question: How can i write bash script, that asks user for hostname, replaces the listen and connect_address lines then asks for name and replaces it in "name" line.
And how can i loop this script?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [ansible's template feature](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html). Basically, you take a copy of your .conf file, and you replace any values you need to dynamically define with jinja2 formatted variables. it may look like this:

```
scope: postgres
name: {{ desired_name }}

restapi:
    listen: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8008
    connect_address: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8008

etcd:
    host: 10.0.13.247:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.242/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.243/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.244/24 md5
    - host replication replicator 10.0.13.245/24 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: 10.0.13.243:5432 
    connect_address: 10.0.13.243:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: replicator_pass
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: postgres
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

Now,  the template module works very similarly to the copy module, as it just moves the conf file from the ansible server to the destination (you specify source and destination in the playbook). What is different is that, for each variable in there ansible fills in information. This can be from facts, this can be from a file, in the playbook, added as additional args to the command you run, [or even prompted for during playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html).

In my example, the ip address would be retrieved from the target host and inserted into the conf file when transfered, and the desired_name variable would need specified, either with a prompt via the method linked above or the --extra-args flag on the ansible command you ultimately run.